# (view-based) NSTableView's reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes: not removing row view?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

Trying to use `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` for my view based `NSTableView` in 10.7. Having redraw problems though. If I edit the object and call reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes: and later delete the object, I end up with a static row view.

To [docs warn](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> For view-based table views, reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:
>   will drop the view-cells in the table row, but not the NSTableRowView
>   instances.

Not sure how I should tell the table view to drop the row view too. If I use reloadData everything works but obviously it's a lot heavier a method to call and causes loss of selection.

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Added a demo app to demonstrate the bug. Can be found on GitHub. It has workaround code but none-the-less I'd still like to find the answer.

https://github.com/zorn/NSTableView-ViewBased-ReloadRowBug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I fixed this bug. Turns out you have to be careful about closing with `[self.tableView endUpdates]` before attempting any kind of `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` on the tableview.

I'll append my radar requesting a formal console working be logged when attempting to do such a thing.

GitHub project has been updated.